# How do I iterate SelectListItem's with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, razor, selectlistitem

Serverside: I make the ViewBag of type "IEnumerable"

Cliectside: Iterate the ViewBag, to build the dropdown.

How can I iterate my SelectListItems with JavaScript/jQuery?

Firefox error message: "TypeError: list.each is not a function"

```
function test() {
    var modtagerId = $('#ModtagerId');
    modtagerId.empty();

    // ViewBag.dropdownModtagerListeNyhedsbrev is of type "IEnumerable<SelectListItem>"
    var list = ViewBag.dropdownModtagerListeNyhedsbrev;

    list.each(function () {
        $("<option />", {
            val: this.value,
            text: this.text
        }).appendTo(modtagerId);
    });
}
```

Comment: .each is a jquery method, is list a jquery object?

Comment: No, // ViewBag.dropdownModtagerListeNyhedsbrev is of type "IEnumerable<SelectListItem>"

Comment: So should I focus on making it (somehow) and jQuery object? Or focus on iterating the object I got allready. There should be a best practice here I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got around this. I used JavaScript `foreach` instead and used `<text>` to escape the Razor.

My solution if anyone cares: (I keept the console.log() for others).

```
function updateModtagerGruppeDropdown() {
    var modtagerId = $('#ModtagerId');
    modtagerId.empty();

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.dropdownModtagerListeVelkomstbrev)
    {
        @:console.log('list: ' + "@(item.Value)" + ", " + "@(item.Text)");
        <text>
            var value = "@(item.Value)";
            var text = "@(Html.Raw(item.Text))";
            $("<option />", {
                val: value,
                text: text
            }).appendTo(modtagerId);
        </text>
    }
}
```